# What data type do you use to pass a dictionary into an httpsCallable function?

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to server side code and I've been trying to switch the database document creation to the server side for account creation. Below I have included the function that I am defining within my xcode project as well as the server side function. After calling the function I get an error saying

> Unhandled error Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "First_Name"). If you want to ignore undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`.

```
class RA_2ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var fNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pNumberField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var countryField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // Check Fields
        if let error = self.validateFields() {
            showError(error)
            
        }else{
            userInfo.updateValue(emailField.text!, forKey: "userEmail")
            userInfo.updateValue(fNameField.text!, forKey: "userFirstName")
            userInfo.updateValue(lNameField.text!, forKey: "userLastName")
            userInfo.updateValue(pNumberField.text!, forKey: "userPhoneNumber")
            userInfo.updateValue(countryField.text!, forKey: "userCountry")
            userInfo.updateValue(cityField.text!, forKey: "userCity")
        
            
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "avatar", sender: self)
        }
        
        }
}
```

```
class PasswordSetUpViewController:UIViewController{
 
    @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if passwordField.text != nil && passwordConfirmationField.text != nil {
            if passwordField.text! != passwordConfirmationField.text! {
                let message = "Passwords must match"
                showError(message)
                return
            }
                userInfo.updateValue(passwordField.text!, forKey: "userPassword")
                let rm = registrationModel(userInfo)
                if userInfo["accountType"] == "Advertiser"{
                    rm.createAdvertiserUser(rm.userEmail!, rm.userPassword!)
                }
                if userInfo["accountType"] == "Influencer"{
                    rm.createBloggerUser(rm.userEmail!, rm.userPassword!)
                }
            if textHelpers.validatePassword(passwordField.text!) == false {
                        let message = "Invalid Password, ensure that password meets the required criteria"
                        showError(message)
                        return
            }
        }
        if passwordField.text == "" || passwordConfirmationField.text == "" {
            let message = "Please fill in both fields"
            showError(message)
            return
        }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "numberConfirmationScreen", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.destination is NumberConfirmationViewController {
            let vc = segue.destination as? NumberConfirmationViewController
            vc?.userInfo = self.userInfo 
        }
    }

}
```

```
class registrationModel {
    var userFN:String?
    var userLN:String?
    var userEmail:String?
    var userPassword:String?
    var userPhoneNum:String?
    var userCountry:String?
    var userCity:String?
    
    var userDOB:String?
    var userContentType:String?
    
    var userCompanyName:String?
    var subscriptionType:String?
    
    var accountType:String?
    
    var userAvatar:UIImage?
    
    
    init(_ userEntries: [String:String]) {
        accountType = userEntries["accountType"]
        userFN = userEntries["userFirstName"]
        userLN = userEntries["userLastName"]
        userEmail = userEntries["userEmail"]
        userPhoneNum = userEntries["userPhoneNumber"]
        userPassword = userEntries["userPassword"]
        userCountry = userEntries["userCountry"]
        userCity = userEntries["userCity"]
        subscriptionType = userEntries["subscriptionType"]
        userDOB = userEntries["userDOB"]
    }

func createAdvertiserUser(_ email:String, _ password:String){
        let advUser = AdvertiserUser(Account_Type: self.accountType!, First_Name: self.userFN!, Last_Name: self.userLN!, Phone_Number: self.userPhoneNum!, Country: self.userCountry!, Subscription_Type: self.subscriptionType!)
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        let data = try! encoder.encode(advUser)
        let valid = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(data)
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
            var functions = Functions.functions()
            functions.httpsCallable("createAdvertiserUserData").call(data) { (result,error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                        let message = error.localizedDescription
                        }
                        // ...
                      }
            }
            if error != nil{
                // Show error
            } else {
                // Successfull user creation

                    
                }
                
            }
        }
```

```
struct AdvertiserUser: Codable{
    var Account_Type: String
    var First_Name: String
    var Last_Name: String
    var Phone_Number: String
    var Country: String
    var Subscription_Type: String
    
}

struct BloggerUser: Codable{
    var Account_Type: String
    var First_Name: String
    var Last_Name: String
    var Phone_Number: String
    var Date_of_Birth: String
    
}
```

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();


exports.createAdvertiserUserData = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {
    if(!context.auth){
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'user must sign in');
    }
    return admin.firestore().collection('users/advertiserUsers/userAccounts').doc(context.auth.uid).set({
        Account_Type: data.Account_Type,
        First_Name: data.First_Name,
        Last_Name: data.Last_Name,
        Phone_Number: data.Phone_Number,
        Country: data.Country,
        Subscription_Type: data.Subscription_Type,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message carefully. It's simply telling you that the value you provided for the First_Name property of the new document was undefined.  That just means that you didn't provide a value *for that one field* in your app.  Since we can't see the value of `self.userFN` in your app, we don't really know what's going on here.

I suggest doing some logging on both your client app and backend function to see the data that's actually being sent and received so you can diagnose if the call is happening the way you expect.

Comment: The values for all fields are stored correctly within my project and can be accessed on the client side. I have included the code depicting so above.

Comment: I don't see any helpful debugging information here.  Please add some logging that shows how this code executes and the values that are being used on both the client and backend so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I have included more of my code above. In my code I store values provided by the user in a dictionary and eventually use the dictionary to make an instance of the RegistrationModel class. I included the server side code on the bottom in TypeScript

Comment: I ran the code in the debugger and was able to see the values stored correctly in the rm variable